# Modify last commit's message and push to upstream

Tags: magit

I'm thinking about automating my following git workflow in emacs:

1. checkout to a new branch
2. remove some pattern in the last commit message
3. commit (amend) it
4. push it to upstream

How could I automate 4 steps in emacs?

And I've tried to combine step 2 and step 3 into one key in magit by:

```js
(defun magit-commit-append-new-msg ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((git-dir (magit-toplevel))
    ;; get last commit msg
    ;; TODO handle remote dir
    (msg (shell-command-to-string (format "git -C \"%s\" log -1 --format=\"%%B\"" git-dir)))
    ;; remove changeid and jira line in msg
    (msg-new (concat msg "[MYTEST]")))
    (magit-git-command-topdir (format "git -C \"%s\" commit --amend -m \"%s\"" git-dir msg-new))))

(magit-define-popup-action 'magit-commit-popup
  ?i
  "Commit with new msg"
  'magit-commit-append-new-msg)
```

But I've not found a way do all 4 steps yet.

Comment: Why do you have to create and checkout a new branch? Am I right in assuming that you are on a branch like `new-feature` and want your modified commit to be pushed to `origin/new-feature`?

Comment: @tarsius The reason I have to checkout a new branch is due to our work process, we have a branch for internal review and before it is pushed to outside we must remove some internal used information from the reviewed commit.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might work.

```
(defun my-fixup-head-message-and-publish (remote branch)
  (interactive
   ;; TODO I don't know your needs you should probably adjust this.
   (list "public"
         (concat "publish/" (magit-get-current-branch))))
  (magit-with-toplevel
    (magit-call-git "branch" branch (magit-get-current-branch))
    (magit-call-git "commit" "--amend" "-m"
                    (concat "[MYTEST]"
                            (magit-rev-format "%B")))
    (magit-call-git "push" branch (concat remote "/" branch)
    (magit-refresh))))
```

You are probably better off asking "please implement this for me" questions on r/emacs.